# How can I prevent the Session.Id from being reset with every request?

Tags: c#, session, asp.net-core-2.2

I have done the session configuration for dotnet core 2.2 and still a new session is created with every request including Session.Id.
So I can't use the session as data holder.

I would like to use the session in connection with a ShoppingCart.

For this I created a separate API project, a separate Service project and a separate SPA project.

here is the ConfigureServices method

```cs
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddAutoMapper();
            // DbContext using SQL Server Provider
            services.AddDbContext<ICleanTasteDbContext, CleanTasteDbContext>(options =>
            {
                options.UseSqlServer(
                    Configuration.GetConnectionString("TasteConnection"),
                    m => m.MigrationsAssembly("Taste.Persistence")
                );
            });
            services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
            {
                options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => false;
                options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
            });
            services.AddDistributedMemoryCache();
            services.AddSession(options =>
            {
                options.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30);
                options.Cookie.IsEssential = true;
                options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
            });
            services.AddHttpContextAccessor();

            // custome services
            services.AddTransient<ICartService<ICart>, CartService>();

            // MVC            
services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);
            // Cors
            services.AddCors();

            services.AddSpaStaticFiles(config =>
            {
                config.RootPath = "wwwroot";
            });
        }
```

and here is the Configure method

```cs
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
                app.UseDatabaseErrorPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseHsts();
            }

            app.UseCors(x =>
                    x.AllowAnyHeader()
                    .AllowAnyMethod()
                    .AllowAnyOrigin()
                    .AllowCredentials()
                    );
            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseDefaultFiles();
            app.UseStaticFiles();
            app.UseCookiePolicy();
            app.UseSession();
            app.UseMvc(routes =>
            {
                routes.MapSpaFallbackRoute(
                    name: "spa-fallback",
                    defaults: new { controller = "fallback", action = "index" }
                );
            });

            app.UseSpa(spa =>
            {
                if (env.IsDevelopment())
                {
                    spa.UseProxyToSpaDevelopmentServer("http://localhost:4200");
                }
            });
        }
```

in the CartsController the service is called as follows

```cs
var cart = await cartService.Add(product);
```

in the CartService class IHttpContextAccessor is injected and called as follows

```cs
var cart = await httpContext.HttpContext.Session.Get<CartModel>(SESSION_NAME);
httpContext.HttpContext.Session.Set<CartModel>(SESSION_NAME, cart);
```

It is set correctly but with the next request there is a new instance of the session and is empty again.

What am I doing wrong?

Can it be related to the fact that I use different projects?

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to say, but there's a couple of potential problems:

1. You're using in-memory sessions, which means you're process-bound. Sessions will never be shared between two different projects because each is a separate running process, with its own memory-backing. Additionally, when the app stops, anything stored in memory goes along with it, so if you stop and restart debugging, for example, or even just rebuild, your sessions go bye-bye. There is not true "distributed" memory cache. It's just an implementation of `IDistributedCache` that uses memory, but it's not *really* distributed.
2. Even if you had a truly distributed session store, each app by default carves out its own place in it, meaning it still won't be shared. You would need to ensure that both apps utilize a common data protection keyring location and that both apps have the same application name set.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.

Even if I only set the session in the API project, it creates a new session after each request.

If I look at the session in the service project, the set keys are visible with value.

The only problem seems to be that it creates a new session with every request.

That the session gets lost in the cases mentioned above is already known to me and does not contradict the UseCase.

Comment: Are you communicating with the API server side or client side?

Comment: Client side. My client is an Angular App.

I have also already started the trial and added the attribute "withCredentials" to the request headers.

Had no effect.